# Mysql subquery difference error

Tags: mysql

Hey guys i am new to mysql actually ..I have wrote two types of code,

## first type

```
select ID,
(select n.NAME from CUSTOMERS as n group by SALARY ) as m
from CUSTOMERS;
```

## second type

```
select ID,
from (select n.NAME from CUSTOMERS as n) as m
group by SALARY;
```

The first one works fine as i expected but the second one didnt ..It throws me error like

`Unknown column 'ID' in 'field list': select ID from (select NAME from CUSTOMERS ) as m group by SALARY`

So by question is can the second way be done in mysql without any errors actually ??

Hope you guys can help me out..Thx

Comment: Not sure what (you think) the second query is doing.

Comment: What you are trying to achieve from query may be there is another better way of doing that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your second one fails because you request column `ID` from a subquery that does not have `ID`:

```
select ID,
from (select n.NAME from CUSTOMERS as n) as m
group by SALARY;
```

It only has `Name`. You will need to add both `ID` and `SALARY` to your subquery if you wish to use them in your main query.

```
select ID,
from (select n.ID, n.SALARY from CUSTOMERS as n) as m
group by SALARY;
```

Also as @Strawyberry pointed out... it's nonsense. You are grouping by a field that isn't in your SELECT clause which... I don't know. You are also subquerying on something that doesn't need to be subqueried. Just do:

```
select m.ID,
from CUSTOMERS as m
group by m.SALARY;
```